# WCF transaction in different threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, wcf, transactions

A client application is calling a WCF-Service in one TransactionScope,  in the hopes of rolling back the entire transaction if the call fails. The Application & Service works fine but if two clients send at the same time request to the WCF-Service, one of the clients gets a deadlock error.

This is the code in the client application:

```
 Using transcop As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, New TransactionOptions() With {.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable})
        Try
            Dim test = LeaProS.RechnungenService.RechnungenInternalWSClient.FacadePdfVerarbeitungInternalWS.PdfVerarbeitungLoslegen(11928, True)

            transcop.Complete()

        Catch ex As Exception
            transcop.Dispose()
            Throw
        End Try
    End Using

Public Shared Function PdfVerarbeitungLoslegen(idAusGeplanteRechnungen As Integer, lettershopDrucken As Boolean) As Byte()

    Dim client As RechnungInternalWSClient = Nothing

    Try
        ' Verbindung zum Webservice initialiseren.
        client = New RechnungInternalWSClient("NetTcpBinding_IRechnungInternalWS")
        client.Open()

        ' verarbeitung starten
        Dim retval = client.PdfVerarbeitungLoslegen(idAusGeplanteRechnungen:=idAusGeplanteRechnungen, LettershopDrucken:=lettershopDrucken)
        client.Close()
        client = Nothing

        'PDF zurückgeben.
        Return retval.pdf

    Catch ex As Exception
        RechnungenUtils.ClientKontrolliertBeenden(client)
        Throw
    End Try

End Function
```

This is the service contract:

```
<ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerCall,
UseSynchronizationContext:=True,
TransactionIsolationLevel:=System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable,
TransactionTimeout:="00:00:30",
ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete:=False
)>
Public Class RechnungInternalWS
Implements IRechnungInternalWS

<OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired:=True, 
TransactionAutoComplete:=True)>
Public Function PdfVerarbeitungLoslegen(idAusGeplanteRechnungen As Integer, 
LettershopDrucken As Boolean) As RechnungPDFOriginal Implements 
IRechnungInternalWS.PdfVerarbeitungLoslegen
' do something
End Function
```

These are the configuration files:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://eldienste:555/IRechnungInternalWS"
binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IRechnungInternalWS"
contract="ServiceReference.IRechnungInternalWS" name="NetTcpBinding_IRechnungInternalWS" />

<binding name="NetTcpBinding_IRechnungInternalWS" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      transactionFlow="True" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="250"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="250"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="2147483646"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
  <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
      enabled="false" />
  <security mode="None">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the right configuration. The service contract must be configured as follows:

- The *ConcurrenyMode* property of the *ServiceBehavior* attribute must be assigned the following *ConcurrencyMode.Multiple* value.
- The *TransactionAutoComplete* property of the *OperationBehavior* attribute must be *true* for all operations. Transactions can not span multiple operations.
- The *ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete* property of the *ServiceBehavior* attribute for the service must be set to *false*. You must explicitly release the service instance by closing the connection from the client.
- The *TransactionAutoCompleteOnSessionClose* property of the *ServiceBehavior* attribute for the service must be *true*. All transactions in all threads must be terminated when the session ends.

  ```
  <ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
  InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
  UseSynchronizationContext:=False,TransactionIsolationLevel:=System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable,
  TransactionTimeout:="00:00:30",
  ReleaseServiceInstanceOnTransactionComplete:=False,
  TransactionAutoCompleteOnSessionClose:=True
  )>
  Public Class RechnungInternalWS
  Implements IRechnungInternalWS


  <OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired:=True, 
  TransactionAutoComplete:=True)>
  Public Function PdfVerarbeitungLoslegen(idAusGeplanteRechnungen As 
  Integer, LettershopDrucken As Boolean) As RechnungPDFOriginal Implements 
  IRechnungInternalWS.PdfVerarbeitungLoslegen

  ' do something
  End Function

  End Class
  ```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that's because you are closing the client before committing the transaction, at least from logical point of view it should look like this:

```
Public Shared Function PdfVerarbeitungLoslegen(idAusGeplanteRechnungen As Integer, lettershopDrucken As Boolean) As Byte()

    Try
        Using transcop As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, New TransactionOptions() With {.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable})
            Using client = New RechnungInternalWSClient("NetTcpBinding_IRechnungInternalWS")
                client.Open()
                Dim retval = client.PdfVerarbeitungLoslegen(idAusGeplanteRechnungen:=idAusGeplanteRechnungen, LettershopDrucken:=lettershopDrucken)
                transcop.Complete()                  
                Return retval
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        RechnungenUtils.ClientKontrolliertBeenden(client)
        Throw
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: I also open the transaction before establishing the connection to the service because before that sql operations are performed. I would like to have everything in one transaction.

Comment: The service contract is configured as follows: TransactionAutoComplete: = True

Comment: The service also works wonderfully. Returning works. Only as soon as two clients access the service at the same time are problems.

Comment: Do you really need Serializable level?